# Undo redo Operation

Tags: ios, swift, undo-redo

I have used the following code for undo redo operation. I am changing the label's background color and my undo/redo operation is working fine but now i have added label's text color so whenever i change only background color or text color individually it works fine but if i change background color and text color both at a time then it will not work properly. what should i do? please help.!

```
@IBOutlet var myObject: UILabel!

//  MARK: - View Life Cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myObject.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
}

func setMyObjectColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        (undoManager?.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self) as AnyObject).setMyObjectColor(myObject.backgroundColor!)
        myObject.backgroundColor = color
}

func setMyObjectTextColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        (undoManager?.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self) as AnyObject).setMyObjectTextColor(myObject.textColor!)
        myObject.textColor = color
}

@IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any){
    setMyObjectColor(UIColor.blue)
}

@IBAction func changeTextColor(_ sender: Any){
    setMyObjectTextColor(UIColor.white)
}

@IBAction func undo(_ sender: Any) {
    undoManager?.undo()
}

@IBAction func redo(_ sender: Any) {
    undoManager?.redo()
}}
```

Comment: Update your question with your code for setting the text (don't worry about the undo/redo part).

Comment: @rmaddy I have given one button for adding text based on click i have managed what ever functionality i needed but the question is once text is added how can i undo or redo it ?

Comment: No one can help if you don't show what text you are referring to. Please update your code with relevant code regarding the text changes you wish to undo/redo. Once you show the text-related code, someone can help with the undo/redo functionality.

Comment: @rmaddy please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet var myObject: UILabel!

//  MARK: - View Life Cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myObject.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
}

func setMyObjectColor(_ Backcolor: UIColor) {
        (undoManager?.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self) as AnyObject).setMyObjectColor(myObject.backgroundColor!)
        myObject.backgroundColor = Backcolor
}

func setMyObjectTextColor(_ Textcolor: UIColor) {
        (undoManager?.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self) as AnyObject).setMyObjectTextColor(myObject.textColor!)
        myObject.textColor = Textcolor
}

func setMyObjectText(_ Text: String) {
    (undoManager?.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self) as AnyObject).setMyObjectText((myObject.text! as AnyObject) as! String)
    myObject.text = Text
}

@IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any){
    setMyObjectColor(UIColor.blue)
}

@IBAction func changeTextColor(_ sender: Any){
    setMyObjectTextColor(UIColor.white)
}

@IBAction func changeText(_ sender: Any) {
    setMyObjectText("Khush")
}

@IBAction func undo(_ sender: Any) {
    undoManager?.undo()
}

@IBAction func redo(_ sender: Any) {
    undoManager?.redo()
}
```

Using this code my issue is solved.

Comment: What does this have to do with your question? All you did was add the `setMyObjectText` and `changeText` methods which have nothing to do with the information or code in your question. This is why I asked you to clarify your question.